# Shift a signal in time using Fourier Transform and Inverse Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am trying to time-shift a signal `x`, which is a sine wave with 10 sec time-period, by `t=2` seconds to get shifted version `y` using Fourier Transform and Inverse Fourier Transform. I am using the following code in *Mathematica*:

```
x := Sin[2*Pi*0.1*t]
fftx := FourierTransform[x, t, ω]
ffty := Exp[I *ω*2]*fftx
y := InverseFourierTransform[ffty, ω, t]

Plot[x, {t, 0, 20}]
Plot[y, {t, 0, 20}]
```

When I try to plot y, I do not get a shifted version of x, as expected. Instead, y is same as x. What's wrong?

Comment: This is garbled code. You need to be multiplying `fftx` by a vector of frequency dependent phase factors, not a scalar, which is what this appears to attempt,

Comment: @JohnDoty I think I'm doing that in ffty.

Comment: Everything in your code is fine in principle. The only thing you did wrong is to use `:=` instead of `=`. Make that replacement everywhere and it will work. I think @JohnDoty misunderstood, maybe was thinking about discrete FT.

Comment: Look up `SetDelayed` to understand the difference to `Set` - it's very important...

Comment: @Jens is right. `FourierTransform` vs `Fourier`. And you fixed the garble.

Comment: @jens Thank you. I will look into `Set` and `SetDelayed`

Comment: @EVERYBODY Thanks.  
I understood the problem. `y:=expr` is only about *storing a definition* for `y`, while `y=expr` is about evaluating the `expr`.  That's why putting `y=InverseFourierTransform[ffty, ω, t]` in the last line just before `Plot` commands works fine.  
As a lesson, `:=` might behave weirdly sometimes. Just be careful.